# Congratulations on getting to private beta

Tags: discussion

I would like to congratulate our community on getting to private beta and thank everyone who has been involved with us since the proposal stage

We need enough activity during the private beta to go into public beta, after which I am hopeful that the site will sustain itself until it becomes fully graduated

Please answer as many questions and answers as you can, as well as participate in moderation activities (voting, editing, closing, reopening, etc.)

If nothing else we can start by asking our own questions from the proposal stage

It seems likely that this is going to be the first time many of the commiters to this proposal will be using stackexchange so here are some links for using features of this site:

[chatrooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=korean.stackexchange.com)
[review (close vote, reopen votes, etc)](https://korean.stackexchange.com/review)
[formatting help](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)